# Copy and paste does not work well

Tags: 10.10, clipboard

I upgraded from 10.04 to 10.10 and having been trying to fix this issue for a couple of weeks with no luck.

Copy and pasting text is really wonky.
Sometimes it works sometimes no matter what I do and copy will paste instead.

I use different programs, thunderbird, firefox and gedit. Sometimes it is fine others I can click all different ways with no luck at all

Things I have tried:

- Installing various clipboard programs. (Seems to be making the issue worse)
- I tried using the esc key also

What does not work:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, mouse right click nor Edit > copy and paste.

I have a Microsoft wireless 1000 keyboard/mouse and dual monitors. Just as a test I put the live CD of 10.04 and could not get the problem to duplicate.
Nvidia graphics card...

Am I so messed up may have to wipe and reinstall 10.04?

Answer (score 4):

You need to know that some programs like Firefox have a special memory place for their "clipboard", while ubuntu has another. you CAN use the clipboard from firefox to another programa in ubuntu only while you have Firefox OPENED. You can not close Firefox if you want to maintain the information you have in the Firefox Clipboard.

This also applies to other programs that do not share the same memory place. Closing the programa you copy from can make the following problems:

1. Copy some info and when you select to paste there is no PASTE option available.
2. Select by dragging the mouse over some text and when you want to paste using the middle scroll button there is nothing to paste.

So at the end you need to have the source program you are copying from opened. Also selecting something by dragging on it and highlighting what you want is different from selecting COPY option. They sometimes have different memory places (Depending on the program). For example in Firefox, highlight something and open gedit and paste using the middle scroll button. It will work. No close firefox and test. No do the same but right click and select COPY.

That way you know how programs relate when using the clipboard or their own clipboard.

Wish there was a universal clipboard.

Another HINT for you is to download glipper. Which saves anything you highlight or copy to a list from where you can grab anytime you want the info.